# How to use CircleImageView in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, imageview, android-imageview

I am using following code forCircleImageView in Android Studio

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:src="@drawable/user"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView"/>
```

i am adding following library in gradle file
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'

But now I want to do this in Eclipse .I have no exprience of eclipse so please help me
How is it possible?

Comment: Why should it differ?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: which library should i used?

Comment: The very same you use in Android Studio. https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Comment: As i think there is no library in this link.

Answer (score 0):

Add the library and use this :

```
CircleImageView b1=(CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn);

b1.setImageResource(R.drawable.my);
```

Comment: which library should i used?

Comment: Any link to download library.

Comment: Try this http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/de.hdodenhof/circleimageview/1.1.0